# Repeated elimination of sets whitch contain a certain subset from a power set

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the set S = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}

Basic combinatorics of no repetition and irrelavant order says the total number of subsets of S is the sum of binomial coefficients of 16 elements from 0 to 16 spaces i.e. 2^n

Therefore 2^16 = 65536 is the total number of subsets of S (elements of the power set)

I am trying to figure out, given a certain set of subsets of S, how to get the number of elements of the power set that do not contain the given subsets

For instance if given the subsets {1, 3, 4}, {1}, {5, 6} I'd want to get the number of subsets of S such that they do not contain those certain subsets.

I want to do this an arbitrary number of times i.e. I want to get a number of subsets of S that do not contain any of the given subsets of S, for instance the sets {1, 3, 4} , {5, 6} , {6, 9, 11, 15, 16} etc.

I can do this manually using some tricky set theory, but it takes up a lot of my time and I'll have to repeat this process maybe hundreds od times, it getting harder every time due to the increased number of overlaps.

I wanted to know if there is some generalization in combinatorics (or set theory) that allows me to stremline (generalize) this process?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do I understand this right: given $A\subset S$, you are looking for the number of sets $B\subset S$ satisfying $A\not\subset B$?

Comment: It's much easier to count the number of subsets which *do* contain the given set.

Comment: @lulu that was going to be my next comment, but It isn't clear to me if this is what is being asked for

Comment: @lulu This is true, but I wish to know the number of subsets that do not contain any of the given subsets, whitch is why I am asking here. Otherwise the anwser is much simpler.

Comment: Ok...so take the total, $2^{16}$ and subtract the number of bad sets.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing the point, as there seems to be no difficulty at all here.  Say $A=\{1,3,4\}$ then $|A^c|=13$ so there are $2^{13}$ subsets of $S$ that contain $A$.  Thus there are $2^{16}-2^{13}$ subsets that don't.  Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: @lulu The problem there is that some sets overlap, for instance if I wanted to eliminate all sets that contain {1, 2} and {2, 3} the set {1, 2 ,3} contains them both  so if I directly substracted the total number of those sets I would substract {1, 2 ,3} twice, giving me an incorrect result

Comment: Your question is phrased very poorly. I thought you were only looking at a single subset (your header refers to "a certain subset"). What is the thing you are trying to count?

Comment: @Inquisitor No, you're not substracting them twice. $2^{16} - 2^{13}$ is correct.

Comment: @lulu The number of subsets of S that do not contain any of a given list of subsets , for instance sets {1}, {2, 3}, {5, 6, 1} etc.

Comment: Well, I suggest editing your post for clarity.  In any case, Inclusion Exclusion does what you want.  Start with the total, subtract those which contain a specified member of your list, add back those that contain two specified members, and so on.

Comment: @jjgmath that would only be correct if I wanted to eliminate only 13 1 element sets, but I am working with the given subsets being any of the possible subsets of S

Comment: I agree with lulu. That was not clear from your statement of the problem. You should edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @lulu edited it now, hopefully it is a clearer

Comment: Yes, I think it is clearer (though "number of times" is still confusing).  As it stands, my comment about Inclusion Exclusion should answer your question, yes?  This is literally what that technique is designed to address.

Comment: @lulu Yes, though I've hoped for some generalization on how to eliminate subsets systematicly from a power set given a set of them, thank you nontheless